# Pandas: What does the compound method is useful for?

Tags: python, pandas

I found pandas [compound dataframe method documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.compound.html) but it is really terse. I've tried to run it on a simple dataframe, but didn't understand its utility. Here is my example:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2), columns=['a', 'b'])

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   a  b
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5

In [7]: df.compound()
Out[7]: 
a    14
b    47
dtype: int32
```

What should I use this method for?

Comment: Column `a` means you earn 0% the first year, 200% the second year and 400% the third, for a total of 15x the original amount, or an increase of 1400%. Time units are made up.

Comment: Its the same as `df.a.add(1).cumprod().sub(1)` . You can see the compounding evolving, and `.compound()` yields just the last number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more like loan calculation -- compound interest

[image]

```
df.compound()
Out[143]: 
a    14
b    47
dtype: int32
```

So for columns `a`

[image]

Comment: Ops, I could have just ctrl-click to see the source: `(1 + self).prod(axis=axis, skipna=skipna, level=level) - 1`